# Wordpress: Print Subcategory Posts Including (Title, Permalink and excerpt) under Category inside page template

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

Hi Basically I have a page template. Like for Table of contents.
I dont want a plugin because I still want to control the code.

I just wanna ask if its this possible?

==> Table of Contents Page (Under Category June Issue)

Then Prints all the subcategory infos under the specific category. like this format :

=> Subcategory title

```
 then Posts Under (this) Subcategory
 -> Post Title including Permalink
 -> Post Excerpt

 -> Post Title including Permalink
 -> Post Excerpt

 -> Post Title including Permalink
 -> Post Excerpt
```

=> Subcategory 2 title

```
 then Posts Under (this) Subcategory
 -> Post Title including Permalink
 -> Post Excerpt

 -> Post Title including Permalink
 -> Post Excerpt

 -> Post Title including Permalink
 -> Post Excerpt
```

=> Subcategory 3 title

```
 then Posts Under (this) Subcategory
 -> Post Title including Permalink
 -> Post Excerpt

 -> Post Title including Permalink
 -> Post Excerpt

 -> Post Title including Permalink
 -> Post Excerpt
```

and so on..

I just want to know if wordpress has this method of extracting subcategories under specific post categories.. How can I show it in the template properly like if Im gonna create another table contents for the next issue It will automatically prints all subcategory infos. please help me.

Thanks

Comment: this is definitely, but what have you tried?

Comment: actually I dont know how to start. Im just beginning to explore on how to explode such subcategories under specific category. would it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...    Not tested

```
<?php 

        $args = array(
            'type'                     => 'post',
            'child_of'                 => 0,
            'parent'                   => '1', //Only get child categories
            'orderby'                  => 'name',
            'order'                    => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty'               => 1,
            'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
            'pad_counts'               => false 
        );

        $categoryList = get_categories($args);

            if(!empty($categoryList)){

            foreach($categoryList as $category){

                          $postArgs = array(
                    'cat' => $category->id,
                            'post_type' => 'post'   //Use other options as needed
                         );                    

                query_posts($postArgs);

                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                echo get_the_title();
                echo get_permalink();
                        echo get_the_excerpt();
                endwhile;

             }

             }
    ?>
```